# how to set `DISPLAY` in acpid scripts

Tags: linux, xorg, acpi

i have multi user logged in, and i use acpid to listen `sleep` key to turn off screen use `xset dpms force off` command.

i can not turn of the screen because acpid run as and excute scripts as root. and i do know how to set correct `DISPLAY`. because every logged in user have there own display, and i don't know which one is currenttly displayed. may be `GNOME` knows, but i don't know how to findout.

Comment: Running `who` I got this `paulo    tty1         2020-02-13 08:47
paulo    pts/0        2020-02-13 08:56 (:0.0)`

Comment: It seems that `who` really doesn't help, the display (:0.0) is from a terminal that I have always opened, so if a user doesn't open a terminal, that output is useless. I found this answer about `w` command https://askubuntu.com/questions/230835/list-existing-x-display-names and it seems that it takes info from `ps`. I think you can filter `ps` output to get the line with user name and the X path server.